# How to get the filetype in lua in nvim

Tags: neovim, vimscript-lua

How to get the current file type in `lua` with `neovim`? I tried following but all of them returns `nil`.

```
print(vim.g.filetype)
print(vim.b.filetype)
print(vim.w.filetype)
print(vim.t.filetype)
print(vim.v.filetype)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`filetype` is a buffer-local option, so you can access it with:

```
vim.bo.filetype
```

From `:h lua-vim-options`:

> ```
> From Lua you can work with editor |options| by reading and setting items in
> these Lua tables:
>
> vim.w
>    ...
>
> vim.bo                                                  *vim.bo*
>        Get or set buffer-scoped |local-options|. Invalid key is an error.
>        Example:
>            vim.bo.buflisted = true
>            print(vim.bo.comments)
>
> vim.wo
>    ...
> ```